# axios: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, https, axios

I'm trying issue a post to a soap web service at following url https://xxx.xxx.gov.ar/AntecedentesService/AntecedentesService.asmx and I get the following error:

```
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1088:19)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
code: 'ECONNRESET',
path: null,
host: 'xxx.xxx.gov.ar',
port: 443,
```

If I issue a post with curl like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @request01.xml https://xxx.xxx.gov.ar/AntecedentesService/AntecedentesService.asmx
```

it works ok. If I try to access it from vscode using the [rest client plugin](https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient.git) I get exaclty the same error, so I guess it could be a problem with node.

Just to dismiss axios, I also tried with https.request following [this example](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback), and I get the same error

Any idea how to solve it?

I'm using node v10.15.3 and axios 0.18.0 from Linux pop-os 4.15.0-48-generic